# How do I logically write the solution for a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to express the solution for a differential equation with symbols.

Is my attempt correct?

$\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t)) \Rightarrow f^{-1}(x(t))=x_{0}(t)$

If not, how should I write it?

Comment: How do you even know that $f^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: I'm trying to generalize a differential equation with a solution

Comment: But the inverse of a function doesn't exist in general.

Comment: So my attempt is wrong? Is there a proper way of writing this without having to use english or such?

Comment: Just define the solution space $\mathcal{L}_f := \lbrace g \text{ solves }\dot{x} = f(x) \rbrace$. There's not much more you can do.